# Spring boot application- org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I developed spring boot app in eclipse kepler, it is working fine.For some reasons i shifted to STS, the same application is giving no such bean exception error. base package given in component scan is not taking all the packages. Application boot class is in com.fmc.tsi.integration.starter. Beans I needed are  in different packages like com.fmc.tsi.*.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fmc.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fmc.tsi</groupId>
     <artifactId>tsimediatorservice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>tsimediatorservice</name>

<properties>
<spring.integration.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <finalName>tsimediatorservice</finalName>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.9</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Exception

```
LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:38 - Application failed to start   due to   an exception org.springframework.beans.factory. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fmc.tsi.integration.inbound.LoanSettlementPaymentGateway' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
Thanks for your help.
```

Comment: please provide us your pom.xml and the whole error log

Comment: @rieckpil, added pom.xml and error description

Comment: Well One of your bean needs a bean of type LoanSettlementPaymentGateway, but there isn't one. You need to read the error message. And if you don't understand why there is no such bean, then post the relevant code and explain why you think there should be one. Also, post the **complete** exception stack trace, as code, so that it's properly formatted.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for responding, you need to read my issue description,  i understand the issue, bean is not getting created. I didn't get, why Spring is not creating the beans , i mentioned in component scan.I feel , it's not recognizing the packages.

Comment: @sreenivas *bean is not getting created*: but you're not showing why you think it should be. How and where is it defined? We can't see your code if you don't post it. I asked to post the relevant code, and you didn't. I also asked you to post the complete exception stack trace, as code, and you didn't.

Comment: Just providing package name in component scan won't help spring to create beans. You have to use annotate you classes or provide the beans information in spring xml config. I think you are missing beans config and then trying to autowire that bean. And yes i agree with @JBNizet you should provide proper logs and code...else the community won't be able to provide you proper solution.

Comment: thank you guys. I have to use @integrationcomponentscan instead of component scan as my application is spring boot with spring integration.